# jboss-as-7.1.1.Final boot issue

Tags: java, jboss7.x

I am getting JBAS015956: Caught exception during boot: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS014643: Could not delete /usr/share/jboss-as/standalone/configuration/standalone_xml_history/20130730-193027234/standalone.v1.xml while booting Jboss AS server 7.1.1.Final

Can any one please help. Following is the stack trace.

```
03:38:19,564 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011802: Starting   Naming Service
        03:38:19,779 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
    03:38:19,900 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
    03:38:19,945 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
    03:38:20,354 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
    03:38:21,385 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-2) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--0.0.0.0-8080
    03:38:21,928 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Listening on /0.0.0.0:4447
    03:38:21,933 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017100: Listening on /0.0.0.0:9999
    03:38:22,041 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /usr/share/jboss-as/standalone/deployments
    03:38:22,056 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found tradecraftesb-1.0.0.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called tradecraftesb-1.0.0.war.dodeploy
    03:38:22,507 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
    03:38:22,560 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015956: Caught exception during boot: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS014643: Could not delete /usr/share/jboss-as/standalone/configuration/standalone_xml_history/20130730-193027234/standalone.v1.xml
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationFile.deleteRecursive(ConfigurationFile.java:441) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationFile.deleteRecursive(ConfigurationFile.java:437) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationFile.createHistoryDirectory(ConfigurationFile.java:422) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationFile.successfulBoot(ConfigurationFile.java:273) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.BackupXmlConfigurationPersister.successfulBoot(BackupXmlConfigurationPersister.java:65) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.finishBoot(AbstractControllerService.java:195) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:268) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:155) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]

    03:38:22,573 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015957: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you running JBoss as a separate service or part of some IDE?

Comment: Ass a seperate service in linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a permission issue.

Please check the permissions of /usr/share/jboss-as/standalone/configuration/standalone_xml_history folder and it seems that folder is not writable.

To solve this, please run the following command to change the permission of that folder and then try to restart Jboss.

```
sudo chmod +w usr/share/jboss-as/standalone/configuration/standalone_xml_history
```

Comment: Thank you Anton but the folder has already permission drwxrwxr-x

Comment: can you please share the link, plus I have automated script that restart the server everyday and is causing problems

Comment: Okay, as stated at https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Configuration+file+history , you may delete the history directory and any files in it at any stage.  
So consider cleaning /20130730-193027234/standalone.v1.xml manually and then restart. You may need to create a backup of the folder before doing this.

Comment: Hey Is this possible due to a deployed application

Comment: I don't think it may cause any problems, since it's history. However be careful, as for instance deleting tmp folder does have an impact on running app sometimes.

Comment: Hey I got the problem, the folders belonged to other user as the environment was cloned from some other location. therefore jboss did not have valid permission to delete them. thanks for the support